# Window updates only when it resizes in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

The application should display an image from a grid of pixels. The color of all pixels should change 30 times per second. After starting the app works for a few seconds and after that the pixels updates will stop. When window resized the pixels updating resumes. With a long-term update of the pixel network, the CPU consumption increases greatly. I tested it on Windows and there the pixel update stops almost immediately. Used the Threading library, and the PyQt5 library to display the interface. How can I make a stable pixels updates in grid?

Here is my code:

```
from random import choice, randint
from sys import argv
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPalette
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFrame, QGridLayout, QMainWindow,
                             QMenu, QToolBar, QWidget)


class EmulatorWindow(QMainWindow):
    spacing = None
    app_running = True

    def __init__(self, spacing=1, screen_resolution=(16, 16)):
        super().__init__()
        self.spacing = spacing

        # Pixel Grid
        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.grid.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.grid.setSpacing(self.spacing)
        for x in range(0, screen_resolution[0]):
            for y in range(0, screen_resolution[1]):
                pixel = QWidget()
                pixel.setAutoFillBackground(True) 
                self.grid.addWidget(pixel, y, x)

        # Application thread
        self.applicationThread = Thread(target=self.applicationRunner, args=())
        self.applicationThread.start()

        # Window Properties
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 450, 495)
        self.setWindowTitle('Pixels Grid')

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(self.grid)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(450, 495))
        self.show()

    def applicationRunner(self):
        color = 0
        while True:
            if self.app_running == False:
                break
            for x in range(0, 16):
                for y in range(0, 16):
                    self.grid.itemAtPosition(x, y).widget().setPalette(QPalette([Qt.red, Qt.blue, Qt.green][color]))
            sleep(1 / 30)
            color = color + 1
            if color == 3:
                color = 0

    def switchSpacing(self):
        self.grid.setSpacing(self.spacing if self.grid.spacing() == 0 else 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(argv)
    ex = EmulatorWindow()
    app.exec_()
    ex.app_running = False
```

Activity Monitor Screenshot

[image]

In the screenshot is MenuBar and ToolBar, but, they do not affect the problem

Application Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the GUI is not updated with the thread is that Qt prohibits the updating of graphic elements from another thread, for more information read [GUI Thread and Worker Thread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread). A thread should not be used if the task is not heavy, for example if we test when it consumes changing a color using the following code:

```
t = QtCore.QElapsedTimer()
t.start()
pal = QtGui.QPalette([QtCore.Qt.red, QtCore.Qt.blue, QtCore.Qt.green][self._color])
for x in range(self.grid.rowCount()):
    for y in range(self.grid.columnCount()):
        w = self.grid.itemAtPosition(x, y).widget()
        if w is not None:
            w.setPalette(pal)
self._color = (self._color +1) % 3
print(t.elapsed(), " milliseconds")
```

Obtaining the following results:

```
4  milliseconds
2  milliseconds
2  milliseconds
3  milliseconds
2  milliseconds
3  milliseconds
3  milliseconds
2  milliseconds
3  milliseconds
# ...
```

Supporting my statement that it is not a heavy task so in this case you should use a QTimer that allows you to do periodic tasks:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class EmulatorWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, spacing=1, screen_resolution=(16, 16)):
        super().__init__()
        self.spacing = spacing
        # Pixel Grid
        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.grid.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.grid.setSpacing(self.spacing)
        for x in range(screen_resolution[0]):
            for y in range(screen_resolution[1]):
                pixel = QtWidgets.QWidget(autoFillBackground=True)
                self.grid.addWidget(pixel, y, x)
        # Window Properties
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 450, 495)
        self.setWindowTitle('Pixels Grid')

        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        widget.setLayout(self.grid)
        self.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(450, 495))
        self._color = 0
        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self, interval=1000/30, timeout=self.applicationRunner)
        timer.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def applicationRunner(self):
        pal = QtGui.QPalette([QtCore.Qt.red, QtCore.Qt.blue, QtCore.Qt.green][self._color])
        for x in range(self.grid.rowCount()):
            for y in range(self.grid.columnCount()):
                w = self.grid.itemAtPosition(x, y).widget()
                if w is not None:
                    w.setPalette(pal)
        self._color = (self._color +1) % 3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = EmulatorWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```